# Ionic native Zip plugin always returns "Failed" while decompressing the zip file with Russian name

Tags: android, ionic-framework, zip, unzip

I'm using the native Zip plugin for Ionic and developing an app for Android (from here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zip/). I download a zip file from a server and store it in the file.externalDataDirectory. I can find it in the folder and decompress it manually on my device. But when I try to unzip it programatically using the plugin, it always returns -1, which means it failed.

Here is my code below, and even the progress function is not called. The file name containes underscore.

`this.zip.unzip(this.file.externalDataDirectory + "my_file.zip", this.file.externalDataDirectory, 
                      (progress) => console.log('Unzipping, ' + Math.round((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100) + '%'))
                .then((result) => {
                  if(result === 0) console.log('SUCCESS');
                  if(result === -1) console.log('FAILED');
                })`

I also tried to hardcode the path, but the result is the same:

`this.zip.unzip(" file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/my_file.zip", "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/", 
                      (progress) => console.log('Unzipping, ' + Math.round((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100) + '%'))
                .then((result) => {
                  if(result === 0) console.log('SUCCESS');
                  if(result === -1) console.log('FAILED');
                })`

Can anyone help me, please?

**EDIT**: I found out that the problem occurs only if the name of the file inside zip is in Russian. The zip archive name itself contains of only digits though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the solution. I've modified the plugin's Java file and added a charset parameter to the constuctor Charset.forName("CP1251"):

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream, Charset.forName("CP1251"));
```